# can we instrument UPC code with PAPI API calls

Tags: upc, papi

I want to instrument my UPC program with PAPI APIs to get information on hardware counters during the execution of UPC program.

But i keep getting linking errors for eg, `"undefined reference to PAPI_read"` `undefined reference to PAPI_library_init` etc

The command I'm giving is 
`upcc -L/full/path/to/libpapi.a -o upcMatrxMultplction upcMatrxMultplction.o`

Any suggestions ?

Does PAPI support UPC compiler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-L provides a directory, not a think to link with.  you should either provide the /full/path/to/libpapi.a as a link argument (along with *.o), or else use "-L/full/path/to -lpapi".  the latter is a bit more conventional.

also, linking can be order-dependent, so I prefer to list all to-link objects first and end the line with -o whatever.